# How to pass the Job name and build number as parameter to another jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins Jobs - *JobA* and *JobB*.

I need to start execution of *JobB* when *JobA* has finished building and I need to pass the Job name (i.e. 'JobA') and the latest build number (the  build that just completed) to *JobB*.

Along with these, I also need to pass the original parameters that were passed to *JobA*, to be passed to *JobB*

I have added a post build action in *JobA* - *Trigger parameterized build on other projects* and specified *JobB* in the *projects to build*. within this, I have also added a parameter - *Current build parameters*, which will pass the current parameters to the next job.

I have also added a build trigger in *JobB* - *Build after other projects are built* and specified *JobA* as the Project Name.

Now, how do I pass the jobName and buildNumber of *JobA* to *JobB*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, I was able to figure this out myself:

I created 2 String parameters in *JobB* - *JOBNAME* and *BUILDNUM*

Then, in the *Trigger parameterized build on other projects* section within the Post-build Action of *JobA*, I added two things:

1. Current Build Parameters
2. Predefined Parameters

Predefined paramters:

```
JOBNAME=${JOB_NAME}
BUILDNUM=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Using these, I was able to pass the job name and build number along with all the current parameters to the next job.

Comment: what type of parameters you created on JobB for JOBNAME and BUILDNUM ? String ? Empty Default ?

Comment: It was String Parameter.

Comment: When I tried this, it didn't pass the build number correctly.  e.g. instead of the build number "201906041" that was generated as configured under "Create a formatted build number" it passed the raw build number "195".  Any suggestions how I would correct the configuration to fix that?

Comment: hmm interesting. I've never tried formatted build numbers before, Are you doing something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252515/jenkins-version-number-plugin-build-number?


I'm guessing It might be stored under a different name in the environment variables..  try passing that instead