# Jenkins Version Number Plugin BUILD_NUMBER

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I would like to use the **Version Number Plugin** to format the BUILD_NUMBER variable.

I've configured it in the following way: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg4fy.png)

Environment Variable Name: FORMATTED_BUILD_NUMBER
Version Number Format String: ${BUILD_NUMBER,XXX}

But when I'm using the FORMATTED_BUILD_NUMBER variable (${FORMATTED_BUILD_NUMBER}) it returns the un-formatted build number.

So I would like to see something like: 032 but it returns 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. Formatting of the strings is done in function [formatVersionNumber](https://github.com/jenkinsci/versionnumber-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/tools/versionnumber/VersionNumberCommon.java). It does not use the [token macro](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin) plugin but parses the string itself, and only considers the variables it mentions in its documentation (`BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED` et cetera). I'd guess the latter does not allow to pad a string to a given length.

[The docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin) are not complete in this regard. You wouldn't know this plugin supports padding at all if you not happen to read the `BUILD_DAY` table entry.